# Existence of finite morphism to projective line

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, complex-geometry

As we all know, Belyi's theorem says: A complex curve $X$ is defined over a number field, if and only if there exists a finite morphism $t:X\to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ with at most $3$ critical points. (I borrow the statement in this paper [[1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0108222)]) Throughout the paper, I cannot find the proof of the existence of finite morphism $t:X\to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$. Is it clear? I think that I missed something. Anyone who can give me a brief reason, it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I think he says that "only-if" direction is Lemmas 3.4 - 3.6.

Comment: @SpamIAm What Lemma assert the existence of finite morphism? When I assume the existence of finite morphism from $X$ to projective line, I can understand the 'at most' part.

Comment: Ah, I see, Lemma 3.6 only provides a morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Choose a non-empty affine  open subset $U\subset X$.
 Then any regular non-constant function $t_0\in \mathcal O(U)$ extends to a rational function $f\in Rat(X)$ which gives you a finite morphism $t:X\to \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$.

2) If you know Riemann-Roch, here is another proof: choose a point $x\in X$ and consider the divisor $D=(g+1)\cdot x$ ($g=$ genus of $X$) and its associated line bundle $\mathcal O(D)$.
Then by Riemann-Roch $ h^0(X,\mathcal O(D))=h^1(X,\mathcal O(D))+1-g+(g+1)\geq 2$.
Hence there exists a non constant $t\in H^0(X,\mathcal O(D))\subset Rat(X)$ and that $t$ will give you the desired finite morphism $t:X\to \mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$.

Comment: Where is being defined over a number field used?

Comment: @rghthndsd: nowhere!